# Spring and Tomcat: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I have an application that uses the Spring Repository framework and a MySQL database. I currently have it deployed on Tomcat 7.

Once I deploy and attempt to log into the application (the first call to the database) I receive the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/waypoint/WEB-INF/classes/repository-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

I have enabled query logging on the database and can confirm that a query is being made to the database for a user object. However, on the login page itself, I see the following message:

```
Your login attempt was not successful, try again.

Reason: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

To make things a bit more confusing, this only happens when I try deploying on a remote server. When I start a local instance of MySQL and run an instance of Tomcat on localhost, everything works as expected.

Below is my repository-context.xml:

```
    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/waypoint_dev" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </beans:property>
    <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes> -->
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan"
        value="com.cigna.waypoint.repository, com.cigna.waypoint.core" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</beans:bean>
```

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing the problem? Is there a configuration that is needed with Tomcat that I am not aware of, or have forgotten?

Thanks for your help.

=== UPDATE 1 ====

After specifying the dialect, I am receiving the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 161,752 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar:5.1.33]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1036) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar:5.1.33]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3427) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar:5.1.33]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3327) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar:5.1.33]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar:5.1.33]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar:5.1.33]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar:5.1.33]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar:5.1.33]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar:5.1.33]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2030) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar:5.1.33]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    ... 80 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2914) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar:5.1.33]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3337) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar:5.1.33]
    ... 90 common frames omitted
20:48:32.455 [http-bio-8080-exec-34] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by working through the steps listed in @Soheil 's answer found here:

[Solving a "communications link failure" with JDBC and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql)

It turns out that all I needed was add the hibernate dialect, as @Dhanush Gopinath suggested, and add the following to my my.cnf file:

```
interactive_timeout=180
wait_timeout=180
connect_timeout=180
max_connect_errors=9999
skip-name-resolve
```

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate needs to know the dialect so that it can connect to the underlying database. You need to set the dialect as `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` for MySQL along with the Datasource definition.

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012799/why-do-i-need-to-configure-the-sql-dialect-of-a-data-source) which says why you need dialect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Dhanush. I tried adding the dialect as you suggested, but I am getting a new error: `ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet`. Does this help at all?

Comment: It looks like a connection issue. But I can't comment more on it, unless I see a trace.

Comment: If you would like to take a look, I've added the new stack trace to my question.