# Hibernate converting java int to mysql integer

Tags: mysql, hibernate, dialect

My Entity class has a column which looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "addons")
public class AddonsEntity {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private int addonGroupId;
    private int order;
    private AddonGroupsEntity addonGroupsByAddonGroupId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment") @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy="increment")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

This convert to sql like:

create table addons (id **integer** not null, ....);

As there is nothing like integer in mysql,its throwing an error.

version:

```
'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '4.3.10.Final'
'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-c3p0', version: '4.3.10.Final'
'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.35'
 Mysql Server version: 5.6.25 Homebrew
 Java 1.8
```

SQL Translation:

```
create table addons (
        id integer not null,
        addon_group_id integer not null,
        name varchar(200) not null,
        order integer not null,
        price decimal(2,0) not null,
        addonGroupsByAddonGroupId_id integer not null,
        primary key (id)
    )
```

ERROR:

```
2015-07-21 01:26:13 [] ERROR [Scanner-1] o.h.t.h.SchemaExport [SchemaExport.java:426] HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table addons (id integer not null, addon_group_id integer not null, name varchar(200) not null, order integer not null, price decimal(2,0) not null, addonGroupsByAddonGroupId_id integer not null, primary key (id)) 
2015-07-21 01:26:13 [] ERROR [Scanner-1] o.h.t.h.SchemaExport [SchemaExport.java:427] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order integer not null,price decimal(2,0) not null,addonGroups' at line 5
```

Comment: Please post the error that you are getting?

Comment: ..and which data type you expect at DB side?

Comment: @Amogh: Updated with error

Comment: Actually problem is with column name `order`, `ORDER` is an reserved word in MySQL so that create statement is getting failed. If you are using annotation then try adding adding/modifying annotation `@Column(name="[order]")` in `AddonsEntity` class.

Comment: Along with my answer if you don't want to go changing property by property you can set `<property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers">true</property>` in hibernate config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is not with `integer`. problem is in create statement. As you see in create statement `order` column is created with `order integer not null,...` where as `ORDER` is a reserved word in Mysql.

**If you are using annotations, solution is**

```
@Column(name = "[ORDER]", nullable = false)
    public int getOrder() {
        return this.order;
    }
```

Or

```
@Column(name = '"ORDER"', nullable = false)
    public int getOrder() {
        return this.order;
    }
```

**If you are using hbm file, solution is:**

```
   <property name="order">
            <column name="[ORDER]" not-null="true" />
   </property>
```

Or

```
<property name="order">
    <column name='"ORDER"' length="255" not-null="true" />
</property>
```

Comment: Along with this if you don't want to go changing property by property you can set `<property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers" value="true"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your application is not correctly configured to use the [`MySQLDialect`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQLDialect.html). How to properly configure Hibernate depends on the environment you are executing it in, so please have a look at the proper documentation.

A starting point for this might be the Stack Overflow Question "[Why do I need to configure the SQL dialect of a data source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012799/why-do-i-need-to-configure-the-sql-dialect-of-a-data-source)"