# MySQL driver configuration in spring

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

What is the difference between these 2 properties in spring ?

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

and

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
```

`spring.datasource.driver-class-name` property seems to work but in some siturations like putting a unquie constraint on column it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012799/why-do-i-need-to-configure-the-sql-dialect-of-a-data-source

Comment: @Lesiak great link ,but it just explains the dialect property not the driver-class-name.

Comment: driver-class-name simply specifies which library is used to connect to the DB. Although the interfaces to SQL databases are standardised as JDBC, the details of implementation (wire protocol etc) vary between databases, hence the need for different drivers

Comment: @Lesiak thanks i got it.should i delete the question?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your question, SO is a good place for both basic and complicated problems