# I have an error in the database Tables, also in the controller

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, controller, backend

The first problem occurs with the database table

---

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "book")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Book {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "book_id")
private Long id;
private String name;
private String publisher;
private String author;
private String aboutBook;
private String fragment;
private int date;
private int volume;
private int quantity;
private int price;
private int discount;
private Boolean bestseller;
private String bookLink;

public Optional<String> getBookLink() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(bookLink);
}

public void setBookLink(String bookLink) {
    this.bookLink = bookLink;
}

public List<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "users_books",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
private List<User> users;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "books_genres",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id"))
private Set<Genre> genres;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "books_languages",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "language_id"))
private Set<Language> languages;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "books_types",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "type_id"))
private Set<Type> types;



@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Book book = (Book) o;
    return date == book.date &&
            volume == book.volume &&
            quantity == book.quantity &&
            price == book.price &&
            discount == book.discount &&
            id.equals(book.id) &&
            name.equals(book.name) &&
            publisher.equals(book.publisher) &&
            author.equals(book.author) &&
            aboutBook.equals(book.aboutBook) &&
            fragment.equals(book.fragment) &&
            bestseller.equals(book.bestseller);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id, name, publisher, author, aboutBook, fragment, date, volume, quantity, price, discount, bestseller);
}

}
```

---

genre table

---

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "genre")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Genre{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "genre_id")
private Long id;

private String name;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "book_genre",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"))
private List<Book> books;
}
```

---

language table

---

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "language")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Language {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "language_id")
private Long id;

private String name;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "book_language",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "language_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"))
private List<Book> books;
}
```

---

role table

---

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "role")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "role_id")
private Long id;

private String name;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
private Set<User> users;

@Override
public String getAuthority() {
    return name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

}
```

---

type table

---

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "type")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Type{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "type_id")
private Long id;

private String name;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "book_type",
        joinColumns =@JoinColumn(name = "type_id") ,
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"))
private List<Book> books;
}
```

---

user table

---

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "user")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "username")
private String username;
@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "number_of_phone")
private Long number;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles;

public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

}
```

---

I get this error

---

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table book_genre drop constraint FK8l6ops8exmjrlr89hmfow4mmo" via JDBC Statement
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:387) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:371) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:341) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:235) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:156) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:128) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:153) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:81) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) [spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) [spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) [spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) [spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) [spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) [spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) [spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) [spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) [spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) [spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
at com.ebook.EBookApplication.main(EBookApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "book_genre" does not exist
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:329) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:315) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:291) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:286) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
... 40 common frames omitted
 org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table book_genre drop constraint FK52evq6pdc5ypanf41bij5u218" via JDBC Statement
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:387) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:371) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:341) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:235) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:156) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:128) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:153) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:81) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) [spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) [spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) [spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) [spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) [spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) [spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) [spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) [spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) [spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) [spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
at com.ebook.EBookApplication.main(EBookApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
 Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "book_genre" does not exist
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:329) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:315) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:291) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:286) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
... 40 common frames omitted
```

---

I also have a problem with the books controller

---

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/books")
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class BookController {
private final BookService bookService;
private final UserService userService;
private final GenreService genreService;
private final TypeService typeService;
private final LanguageService languageService;

@Autowired
public BookController(BookService bookService, UserService userService, GenreService genreService, TypeService typeService, LanguageService languageService) {
    this.bookService = bookService;
    this.userService = userService;
    this.genreService = genreService;
    this.typeService = typeService;
    this.languageService = languageService;
}

@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<Book>> getAll() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(bookService.getAllBooks(), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@PostMapping(
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Book> create(CreateBookRequest request) {
    Book saved = bookService.create(request);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(saved, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

@GetMapping(
        path = "/{bookId}",
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Book> get(@PathVariable Long bookId) {
    Book book = bookService.getById(bookId);
    if (book == null) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(book);
    }
}

@PatchMapping(
        path = "/{bookId}",
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Book> patch(@PathVariable Long bookId,
                                  @RequestBody PatchBookRequest patchRequest) {
    Book book = bookService.getById(bookId);
    if (patchRequest.getGenreId() != null) {
        book.getGenres().add(genreService.getGenreById(patchRequest.getGenreId()));
    }
    if (patchRequest.getLanguageId() != null) {
        
    book.getLanguages().add(languageService.getLanguageById(patchRequest.getLanguageId()));
    }
    if (patchRequest.getTypeId() != null) {
        book.getTypes().add(typeService.getTypeById(patchRequest.getTypeId()));
    }
    if (patchRequest.getUserId() != null) {
        book.getUsers().add(userService.getUserById(patchRequest.getUserId()));
    }
    Book patched = bookService.replace(book);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(patched);
}

@GetMapping(value = "/{bookId}/file")
public byte[] downloadBookFile(@PathVariable("bookId") Long id) {
    return bookService.downloadBookFile(id);
}

@PostMapping(value = "/{bookId}/file", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public void uploadBookFile(@PathVariable("bookId") Long id, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    bookService.uploadBookFile(id, file);
}
}
```

---

```
public class AddBookIdRequest {
public Long bookId;

public Long getBookId() {
    return bookId;
}

public void setBookId(Long bookId) {
    this.bookId = bookId;
}
}
```

---

this class for my request

---

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class CreateBookRequest {
private String name;
private String publisher;
private String author;
private String aboutBook;
private String fragment;
private int date;
private int volume;
private int quantity;
private int price;
private int discount;
private Boolean bestseller;
private String bookLink;
}
```

---

this class connects the book to other tables

---

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class PatchBookRequest {
private Long userId;
private Long languageId;
private Long typeId;
private Long genreId;
}
```

---

my bookServiceImpl

---

```
@Service
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {
private final FileBooksStore fileBooksStore;
private final BookRepository repository;

@Autowired
public BookServiceImpl(FileBooksStore fileBooksStore, BookRepository bookRepository) {
    this.fileBooksStore = fileBooksStore;
    this.repository = bookRepository;
}

@Override
public Book create(CreateBookRequest request) {
    Book book = Book.builder()
            .name(request.getName())
            .publisher(request.getPublisher())
            .author(request.getAuthor())
            .aboutBook(request.getAboutBook())
            .fragment(request.getFragment())
            .date(request.getDate())
            .volume(request.getVolume())
            .quantity(request.getQuantity())
            .price(request.getPrice())
            .discount(request.getDiscount())
            .bestseller(request.getBestseller())
            .build();
    return repository.save(book);
}

@Override
public void uploadBookFile(Long bookId, MultipartFile file) {
    if (file.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot upload empty file");
    }

    Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<>();
    metadata.put("Content-Type", file.getContentType());
    metadata.put("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.getSize()));

    String path = getBookPath(bookId);
    String fileName = String.format("%s", file.getOriginalFilename());

    try {
        fileBooksStore.upload(path, fileName, Optional.of(metadata), file.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to upload file", e);
    }
}

@Override
public byte[] downloadBookFile(Long bookId) {
    Book book = getById(bookId);
    if (book == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Book %s not found", bookId));
    }
    String path = getBookPath(book.getId());

    return book.getBookLink()
            .map(key -> fileBooksStore.download(path, key))
            .orElse(new byte[0]);
}

private String getBookPath(Long id) {
    return String.format("%s/%s", BucketName.INFORMATION.getBucketName(), id);
}


@Override
public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
    return repository.findAll();
}

@Override
public @Nullable Book getById(Long bookId) {
    return repository.findById(bookId).orElse(null);
}

@Override
public Book replace(Book book) {
    return repository.save(book);
}
}
```

---

```
@Service
public class GenreServiceImpl implements GenreService {
private final GenreRepository repository;

@Autowired
public GenreServiceImpl(GenreRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}

@Override
public List<Genre> getAllGenres() {
    return repository.findAll();
}

@Override
public List<String> getNamesOfGenresToList() {
    List<Genre> genres = repository.findAll();
    List<String> stringList=genres.stream()
            .map(genre-> genre.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return stringList;
}

@Override
public Genre getGenreByName(String name) {
    return repository.getGenreByName(name);
}

@Override
public Genre getGenreById(Long id) {
    return repository.findById(id).get();
}
}
```

---

**other classes have the same implementation**

---

Comment: Where is your `book_genre` entity code?

Comment: Try manually dropping your database.

Comment: I tried to delete manually several times, I also tried Maven Clean

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your hibernate.dialect is incorrect based on database you use.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012799/why-do-i-need-to-configure-the-sql-dialect-of-a-data-source)

Comment: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
I use postgres and everything is spelled out here